# How to select on MySQL varbinary column using PHP Doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to select against binary data in a MySQL table using Doctrine 2 ORM (version 2.4.7) and am having difficulties. My table layout is as follows:

`` CREATE TABLE `EmailAddresses` (
  `EmailAddressId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmailAddress` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmailAddressId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EmailAddress_UNIQUE` (`EmailAddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ``

The information I am storing inside of the table is an encrypted using a php version of mysql aes_encrypt. I would rather do this programmatically outside of the database since, that I know of, you cannot make the ORM do this for you. My code to encrypt is (this is just a snippet):

```
const MYSQL_ENCRYPTION_CIFER = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
const MYSQL_ENCRYPTION_MODE = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

/**
 * @param string $valueToEncrypt The value to encrypt. This cannot be empty!
 * @param string $encryptionKey The encryption key. This cannot be empty!
 * @return string
 * @throws EncryptionException
 */
public function mysqlAesEncrypt($valueToEncrypt, $encryptionKey){
    if(IsEmpty::any($valueToEncrypt, $encryptionKey)){
        throw new EncryptionException("Error before encrypting: Encryption value or key cannot be empty!");
    }
    /** @var \Utility\Mcrypt $mcrypt */
    $mcrypt           = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('McryptUtility');
    $paddedValue      = $this->mysqlPad($valueToEncrypt);
    $encryptedValue   = $mcrypt->encrypt(self::MYSQL_ENCRYPTION_CIFER, $encryptionKey, $paddedValue, self::MYSQL_ENCRYPTION_MODE);

    return $encryptedValue;
}

/**
 * Pads a value using PKCS7 padding. This is the padding MySQL uses.
 *
 * @param string $valueToPad
 * @param int $blockSize
 * @return string
 */
private function mysqlPad($valueToPad, $blockSize = 16){
    $length  = $blockSize - (strlen($valueToPad) % $blockSize);
    $padding = str_repeat(chr($length), $length);

    return $valueToPad . $padding;
}
```

My issue is not in the storage - everything works correctly when storing the values to the database. I have tested this by decrypting both programmatically and using MySQL aes_decrypt. When I try to select, though, my server freaks out and actually hits a segfault. I am guessing that the binary data is doing this somehow. Here is the code where I am trying to retrieve the email address entities and it errors. `$email_addresses` is an array of email addresses that have been encrypted using the above encryption method before being passed in.

```
/**
 * @param string[] $email_addresses
 * @return \Entity\EmailAddresses[]
 */
public function retrieveEmailAddressEntities(array $email_addresses){
    return $this->repository->findBy(['EmailAddress' => $email_addresses]);
}
```

The `EmailAddress` column is also set as "binary" inside of the Doctrine 2 entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="EmailAddress", type="binary", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $EmailAddress;
```

Here is the error I'm receiving from the error log:

```
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 91
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/public/index.php:0
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   2. Zend\\Mvc\\Application->run() /var/www/html/public/index.php:22
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   3. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:313
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   4. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   5. call_user_func:{/var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468}() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   6. Zend\\Mvc\\DispatchListener->onDispatch() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   7. Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\AbstractRestfulController->dispatch() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php:113
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   8. Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\AbstractController->dispatch() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php:300
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP   9. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php:116
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  10. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  11. call_user_func:{/var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468}() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  12. Project\\Controller\\ProjectController->onDispatch() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  13. Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\AbstractRestfulController->onDispatch() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Controller/ProjectController.php:38
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  14. Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\AbstractRestfulController->processPostData() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php:414
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  15. Project\\Controller\\Email->create() /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php:456
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  16. Project\\Mailer\\Mailer->send() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Controller/Email.php:48
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  17. Project\\Service\\EmailLogger->logNewEmailSent() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Mailer/Mailer.php:35
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  18. Project\\Service\\EmailLogger->convertToEmailAddressEntities() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Service/EmailLogger.php:45
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  19. Project\\Dao\\EmailAddresses->retrieveEmailAddressEntities() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Service/EmailLogger.php:108
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  20. Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityRepository->findBy() /var/www/html/module/Project/src/Project/Dao/EmailAddresses.php:14
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  21. Doctrine\\ORM\\Persisters\\BasicEntityPersister->loadAll() /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:181
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  22. Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection->executeQuery() /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:930
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  23. Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:828
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.49.1] PHP  24. PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:91
[Tue Jan 27 15:11:06 2015] [notice] child pid 3478 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Not sure what I can do to use Doctrine 2 ORM and also select against varbinary data. Can someone provide some more insight? I have Googled and cannot find any more information. Thanks!

Additional Info:

- Using PHP 5.6
- Zend Framework 2.3
- Doctrine 2 ORM v2.4.7
- Using MySQL 5.5
- CentOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error was coming from Doctrine DBAL. When searching for an array of binary strings, it was causing an error. I have submitted a pull request for this and am currently working with Doctrine devs to get it resolved. Thanks!

Pull request [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/789) for those that are curious.